# sed error -e expression #1, char 2: unterminated address regex

Tags: sed, regular-expression

Trying to write a sed string with multiple commands for a lab for school, and I keep getting same error message. Tried to ask elsewhere for help and they thought I was missing an escape somewhere. I have tried everything to get this to work. Below are some of the various commands I've tried. Original string was :

```
sed “s/,//g” usdeclar.txt | sed “s/://g” | sed “s/;//g” | sed “s/-//g” | sed “s/&//g” | sed “s/\.//g” | sed “/^$d” > sed_edits.txt
```

[image]Please someone help!

Comment: You could narrow the problem down quickly by trying the `sed` commands one-at-a-time to see which one is generating the error. Also, after fixing it, it's generally not necessary to run a lot of `sed` commands in a row; just use `sed -e 'edit1' -e 'edit2' -e 'edit3' ...` or `sed 'edit1; edit2; edit3; ...`

Comment: Welcome to the site. If at all possible, copy-and-paste _all_ console output like you already did for the first example. Also, please add information in what OS and sed` version you are using, there may be slight differences in (expected) behaviour depending on these circumstances.

Comment: This was on a virtual CentOS on VMware Horizon. The step before chaining all the commands together was to actually input them one by one and test them out. Which I had no problem doing. It was only when I had to do this chaining step that I got that error no matter what I tried. Also I did try to single-quote, and that did not work either.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good habit to single-quote your sed expressions, unless you know you want shell expansion of, for example, `$d`. `sed` sees your final expression as

```
sed "/^"
```

if the shell variable `$d` is unset.

(For future debugging purposes, you could've run `sed "(your expression)" usdeclar.txt` for each of your expressions in turn, to find which of them was giving you trouble.)

(And as a sidenote: `tr -d '[-&;.]'` should do the same thing as your first four `sed`s.)

Comment: I suspect the intended final command is `sed '/^$/ d'` (which will delete empty lines).

Comment: Thank you for that sed shortcut! If i can't get this to work properly somehow, I might just use that and get docked the points for not using the chained command.

Answer (score 1):

In your `sed` commands cited as "Original string", you seem to use

```
U+201C  “   e2 80 9c    LEFT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
U+201D  ”   e2 80 9d    RIGHT DOUBLE QUOTATION MARK
```

in lieu of the `"` (0x22) ASCII character. Which neither `sed` nor shell will recognize.

Try using a *nix text editor.

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth your while to search for
sed [[:punc:]]
on the internet.
It would probably shorten your command line.

Comment: It might be worth your while to include a summary of what is said about `[[:punc:]]` on the internet, in your answer. It would probably improve your answer.